# affect only only certain elements of class

Tags: html, css

so I have a class and in that class I have a table and a text object(<p>). I only want to style the table and not the text object but i do not want to style all tables like this. is this possible and if so, how do I do this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id=COA>
<img src="IMG/mainImgsmall.jpg"  alt="Coat of Arms">
</div>
<div id=navBar>
        <table>
                <tr>
                        <td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                        <td><a href="away.html">Away</a></td>
                        <td><a href="test0.html">test0</a></td>
                        <td><a href="test1.html">test1</a></td>
                </tr>
        </table>

<p>hfef</p>
</div>
<p>this is home</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some html code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6cdTkgWT

Comment: navBar(It's a id. Sorry didn't think before I typed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a selector like `#navBar table { ... }`